# Is it possible to output different lines in drawtext for each file in the playlist?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Isn't there something like this

```
ffmpeg -i playlist.txt -vf drawtext="drawtextlist.txt"
```

Where playlist.txt

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file '3.mp4'
```

and drawtextlist.txt

```
fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='For 1.mp4'
fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='For 2.mp4'
fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='For 3.mp4'
```

Is there any solution for playlists?

Comment: Not that I now of, I guess one would have make a script to use different settings for each file...

Comment: know not now.....